# serialize to C# MVC model class from knockout Model

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api

-----knock out js code------------

```
var User = function () {
    this.UserName = ko.observable();
    this.Password = ko.observable();
};


var LoginViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.LoginName = '';
    this.Password = '';
    this.errorvisible = ko.observable(false);

    this.User = ko.observable(new User());
    this.returnurl = '<%: Url.Action("Home","Home") %>';
    this.Login = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/LoginApi/',
            contentType: "Application/Json , UTF-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ko.toJson(self.User()),
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.ID;
                if (result == 400) {
                    self.errorvisible(true);
                } else {
                    self.errorvisible(false);
                    window.location.href = self.returnurl;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    };

};
ko.applyBindings(new LoginViewModel());
```

------User Model class-------------------

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }


  public void Post(User value)
  {
      //This is the post method  the webAPI which should get the values of properties in User class
  }
```

when the debugger hits the Post Method User class instance is Null(i.e Value is Null) 
   instead of the values in the property like UserName and Password

Comment: Your content-type looks strage. Can you just try with `contentType: 'application/json'`?

Comment: Are there any messages in the ModelState? If not download this and observe the output http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.tracing

Comment: Dear @chitta what are you actually doing i mean you are sending data form the UI , if you are then kindly please post your HTML code also

Comment: pls check firebug and fiddler to see what content type and data is being passed to the server

Comment: @nemesv, I am new to Json and knockout
 Thanks it works now

Answer (score 0):

Your content type `contentType: "Application/Json , UTF-8",` is wrong.

It should be :

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
```

or just simply:

```
contentType: 'application/json'
```

Without the correct content type Wep.API cannot process your request correctly so you get the the `null` parameter.